# Why is my DAX Measure working like this when Rows don't relate?

Tags: powerbi, dax

Sorry for the weird title, I really can't find a way to sum up my question.

Here's the deal:

I have these tables:

Table A - Table B - Table C - Table D

Here's how they relate:

Table A to B one to many. (one way)

Table B to C many to one. (Both ways)

Table C to D one to many. (one way).

I have a measure that just sums a column of the D table.

Now, when I make a matrix and I add a column from Table A and the measure, something weird happens.
Rows from table A that don't relate to any rows of table B show the sum of all the rows of table D that don't relate to any rows of table C.

So, when everything relates OK, the measure works OK, but I really don't know why DAX is doing this when they don't, I would just expect a blank result.

I can fix this by filtering the sum, but I just want to understand what is happening.

Sorry if I didn't explain my situation correctly, and thank you very much for any answers

Comment: Please clarify the direction of all your relationships.  And preferably, use the "Enter Data" option in a new PBIX to isolate, examine, and communicate this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a one-to-many relationship, it's expected that the one-side contains all of the distinct values on the many-side. This is called [referential integrity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_integrity).

> all the rows of table D that don't relate to any rows of table C

This means that you have an invalid relationship with orphaned rows in D. Since these orphaned rows are not filtered by table A, they get included in the sum of rows in table A that don't filter table D through the relationship paths.

I recommend reading this article for more detail:

https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/blank-row-in-dax/

Comment: Thank you! I have to think about it a bit more, but I think this part:

If a relationship is invalid, the VertiPaq engine automatically adds a row containing BLANK in every column of the table on the one-side of the relationship – in this case to the Product table

explains the behavior I saw. Since the values were blank and not invalid, I didn't think it would create an issue (it wouldn't on SQL).

Thanks again!